# Form's clean method not getting called

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to create some objects with django's CBV `FormView`
the code for `form_class` is like this:

```
class UrlForm(forms.Form):
    url = forms.CharField(required=True,
                help_text=_("This should be an absolute path, excluding the domain name.\
                             Example: '/events/search/'."),
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style':'width:400px;'}))
    title = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea())
    description = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea())
    keywords = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea())

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UrlForm, self).clean()
        url = cleaned_data.get('url')
        try:
            Url.objects.get(url=url)
            raise forms.ValidationError("Seo Url already exists.")
        except:
            pass
        return cleaned_data
```

and i use this view to render the form:

```
class CreateSeoByUrl(FormView):
    template_name = 'create_seo_by_url.html'
    form_class = UrlForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard:index')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        url = Url.objects.create(url= request.POST.get('url'))
        seo = Seo.objects.create(
                    title = request.POST.get('title'),
                    description = request.POST.get('description'),
                    keywords = request.POST.get('keywords'),
                    content_object=url)

        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

The url should be unique, so i try to raise `ValidationError` if There exists a Url with same value.But the catch is, its not going into form's clean method nor in `form_valid` or `form_invalid`, it simply shoots to post method and tries to create url and seo objects. Why is my form's clean method /form_valid/invalid not getting called .. i am at my wits end !!

Comment: making def post(...) to def form_valid(self, form) did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your post method is wrong. you must either use form_valid method like below

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    url = Url.objects.create(url= form.cleaned_data['url'])
    seo = Seo.objects.create(
                title = form.cleaned_data['title'],
                description = form.cleaned_data['description'],
                keywords = form.cleaned_data['keywords'],
                content_object=url)

    return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

or if you want to use Post method use it like below:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        url = Url.objects.create(url= form.cleaned_data['url'])
        seo = Seo.objects.create(
                title = form.cleaned_data['title'],
                description = form.cleaned_data['description'],
                keywords = form.cleaned_data['keywords'],
                content_object=url)

    return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

I'vent tested the code but it will work. Let me explain why your code didnt worked. In your post method you didnt initialized the form with post arguments. once the form is initialized you can run clean method and it will raise exceptions if any. Also since you are using FormView, there is a form_valid method (my recommendation is to first read before development). Another advice, since you are using form to create object, why not use CreateView and ModelForm.. :)

Answer (score 4):

This won't work because you're overriding entire `post` method in view. That `post` method is by default responsible for calling validation on form and calling `form_valid` or `form_invalid` method after that.

What is the point of using `FormView` if you're not using form at all.

Also: you sholud refer to form's `cleaned_data` instead of `request.POST`. It will contain only fully cleaned data.

Answer (score 2):

When calling clean you have to return clean data with self

```
def clean(self):
    url = self.cleaned_data.get('url')
    try:
        my_url = Url.objects.get(url=url)
        if my_url:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Seo Url already exists.")
    except Url.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    return self.cleaned_data
```